# Gvim: gx to {the same, a new, a vertical-split} window

Tags: gvim, netrw

Say in Gvim I have a line in the current buffer:

```
~/.bashrc
```

How can I access this file (`~/.bashrc`) in the same, or a new, or a vertical-split window?

I tried `gx`, which opens the file with `xdg-open`. It opens the file in a new Gvim session / instance, rather than in the current one.

Comment: Try `gf` instead (`:h gf`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of `gx` is to open the file under the cursor *in an external program.*

Use `gf` to open the file in a new buffer.

Use `<C-w><C-f>` to open it in a new horizontal window then use `<C-w>L` to turn that window into a vertical one.

Comment: Did you mean `<C-w>L` to turn the window to  a vertical split?

Comment: Oops! Yes that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using netrw to see the file you want opened: with the cursor atop the filename, press o (for a horizontal split window) or v (for a vertical split window).  See :help netrw-contents and  :help netrw-quickmaps .  (use p for a preview window)